# Azure Databricks: Read from Unity Catalog with partition?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Is it possible to read a specific partition in Unity catalog? Currently I am using syntax `spark.table(my_catalog.my_database.mt_view)` but this syntax will read the whole dataset. Is it possible to read a specific partition?

Since it is an external table I could use `abfs://my_container@my_storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/<partition>`
Is that the only way to read a specific partition if a table is located in Unity Catalog? If yes, should I always create an external table if I want to read a specific partition in Unity Catalog?

Comment: If you are adding a filter parameter (which corresponds to your partition structure) to your query, basically only the partition/s will be loaded to memory which you have selected.

Answer (score 1):

The read operation like `spark.table("my_catalog.my_database.mt_view")` is a lazy operation (many other operations are lazy as well) - it will just read metadata of the table to understand its structure, column types, etc. It won't read actual data - this will happen when you perform some action on data - write results, display data, etc.

To read only a specific partition, add `.filter("part_column = 'value'")` after `spark.table(...)`.  It also will be a lazy operation - filtering will be applied when you actually process data.

So you don't need to create an external location to read a specific partition.